# How can I get the updated information from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, state, provider

What I'm trying to obtain is a real-time updated value of a variabile stored in Firestore using the Provider package. Without putting the entire code inside here, i with get you a simple, but meaningfull demo.

The main tries to notify the listeners with

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProvider(),
        ...
        ...),
      ],
```

My user provider class:

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
  MyFirestoreUser? _firestoreUser;

  MyFirestoreUser? get getMyFiredtoreUser => _firestoreUser;

  Future<void> updateUserInformation() async {
    MyFirestoreUser firestoreUser = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _firestoreUser = firestoreUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

In the HomeScreen Widget I have something like this:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late UserProvider _userProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Text(_userProvider.getMyFiredtoreUser!.email),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this way I get an exception saying:
`FlutterError(dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _HomeScreenState.initState() completed.`

Do you know how to get a real time value from firestore?
I've understood how providers work and pass the data through the widget tree, but in my case the data are stored in Firestore. How can make a widget a 'Firestore listener'?